# Expansion of inner product for polynomial kernel for SVMs

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, linear-algebra

On page 424 in "The Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie et al (2013) (https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf), we see the following expansion of a polynomial kernel with degree 2:

[image]

I don't understand the second line in this expansion. Why is it possible to expand the inner product $\langle X, X^\prime\rangle$ to $X_1 X^\prime_1 + X_2 X_2^\prime$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it is the usual inner product we commonly use in linear algebra, i.e. $<x,y>=x^Ty$, and the vectors are of dimension $2$, you can write $$<x^Ty>=x_1y_1+x_2y_2$$, because in general we have $$x^Ty=\sum x_iy_i$$
Here, $x=X, y=X’$.