How to find K in kernel trick?
How does one go about finding the kernel when using the so-called "kernel trick?" Here is an example from quora:

Simple Example: x = (x1, x2, x3); y = (y1, y2, y3). Then for the function f(x) = (x1x1, x1x2, x1x3, x2x1, x2x2, x2x3, x3x1, x3x2, x3x3), the kernel is K(x, y ) = (<x, y>)^2.


Let's plug in some numbers to make this more intuitive: suppose x = (1, 2, 3); y = (4, 5, 6). Then:
f(x) = (1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9)
f(y) = (16, 20, 24, 20, 25, 30, 24, 30, 36)
<f(x), f(y)> = 16 + 40 + 72 + 40 + 100+ 180 + 72 + 180 + 324 = 1024


A lot of algebra. Mainly because f is a mapping from 3-dimensional to 9 dimensional space.


Now let us use the kernel instead:
K(x, y) = (4 + 10 + 18 ) ^2 = 32^2 = 1024
Same result, but this calculation is so much easier.

How did she know to choose $K(x,y)=(<x,y>)^2?$ Is there an algorithm one follows to get that? Or is it just trial-and-error? Or a set of heuristics?

The derivation appears in the statement of this question. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/416721/22311 you can find more using a site search.
